# Dragon with orange and black butterfly wings - mass market paperback fantasy short stories

Tags: story-identification, books, cover-art

I saw a mass market paperback at a Waldenbooks in Texas in the early 1990's that was a collection of fantasy short stories, it had front cover art of a dragon or two (maybe green colored) but with very striking orange and black colored butterfly wings that looked like Monarch butterfly wings to me. I didn't buy the book and I have never seen it again even though I have done extensive searching online.  I am pretty sure the book was stories by different authors and that it was published by one of the common fantasy  book publishers.  I would so appreciate your help so that I can find this book for its striking cover art.

Comment: I guess not this, but related: http://www.dragonladyart.com/store/p300/The_Monarch_Print_by_Carla_Morrow.html

Comment: "The Dragons at War": http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?11239 ?

Comment: The book "The Dragons at War" is not it.  The dragon on the cover-art definitely had "butterfly" type orange and black wings.  Although I can't remember a publisher it definitely was not TSR or else I would have bought it.  I think that.the title of the book may have had the word "dreams" in it. I saw this book in the early 1990's probably before 1995.

Answer (score 5):

[The City of the Singing Flame](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?37174) by Clark Ashton Smith

[image: cover]

Comment: Oy. Definition of "chimera", anyone?

Comment: Unfortunately "The City of Singing Flame" cover is not it. I have seen this book several times but the one I am trying to find I have only seen once.  I thought it was a common publisher but after all the looking I have done I am now beginning to wonder..