# Looking for a story with a city walking to war

Tags: story-identification

[Recent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176703/massive-city-structures-that-crawled-over-the-plains-due-to-being-deconstructe) [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176752/mobile-city-book-not-mortal-engines) about moving cities have reminded me of something I read about twenty years ago.  I have no idea how old the story was, how long it was, or even what most of it was about.  I just remember one really striking scene.

The viewpoint character is observing from the (stone?) walls of one city, as another city approaches.  I'm not sure whether the observer's city is permanently stationary, or if it has stopped its own advance to await the enemy city.  The other city is walking on thousands of legs, which support its huge bulk, with high, pointed metal towers, about which red lightning is crackling.

The character never gets to observe what happens when the enemy city catches up.  I think he flees somewhere else for the main part of his adventure, but I don't recall what that would have been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/180415/48874) pointed me to the correct solution to this question.  I was thinking of Clark Ashton Smith's sequel of "[The City of the Singing Flame](http://www.eldritchdark.com/writings/short-stories/26/the-city-of-the-singing-flame)," titled "Beyond the Singing Flame" but usually published as the second half of "City."  While it has some evocative moments, like the walking city that I remembered, the sequel in other ways seems like a betrayal of the original's fatalistic conclusion.

Here's the parts I was thinking of:

> It must have been because I had formed so clear and definite a picture of the scene from my friend's narrative, that I was surprised, and even a little disturbed as if by something wrong or irrelevant, when I saw in the far distance the shining towers of what seemed to be another city -- a city of which Angarth had not written. The towers rose in serried lines, reaching for many miles in a curious arclike formation, and were sharply defined against a blackish mass of cloud that had reared behind them and was spreading out on the luminous, amber sky in sullen webs and sinister, crawling filaments.
>
> Subtle disquietude and repulsion seemed to emanate from the far-off, glittering spires, even as attraction emanated from those of the nearer city. I saw them quiver and pulse with an evil light, like living and moving things, through what I assumed to be some refractive trick of the atmosphere. Then, for an instant, the black cloud behind them glowed with dull, angry crimson throughout its whole mass, and even its questing webs and tendrils were turned into lurid threads of fire.
>
> The crimson faded, leaving the cloud inert and lumpish as before; but from many of the vanward towers, lines of red and violet flame had leaped, like out-thrust lances, at the bosom of the plain beneath them. They were held thus for at least a minute, moving slowly across a wide area, before they vanished. In the spaces between the towers, I now perceived a multitude of gleaming, restless particles, like armies of militant atoms, and wondered if perchance they were living things. If the idea had not appeared so fantastical, I could have sworn, even then, that the far city had already changed its position and was advancing toward the other on the plain.
>
> V. The Striding Doom
>
> Apart from the fulguration of the cloud, the flames that had sprung from the towers, and the quiverings which I deemed a refractive phenomenon, the whole landscape before and about me was unnaturally still. On the strange amber air, the Tyrian-tinted grasses, and the proud, opulent foliage of the unknown trees, where lay the dead calm that precedes the stupendous turmoil of typhonic storm or seismic cataclysm. The brooding sky was permeated with intuitions of cosmic menace, and weighed down by a dim, elemental despair.
>
> Alarmed by this ominous atmosphere, I looked behind me at the two pillars which, according to Angarth, were the gateway of return to the human world. For an instant, I was tempted to go back. Then, I turned once more to the near-by city, and the feelings I have mentioned were lost in an oversurging awesomeness and wonder. I felt the thrill of a deep, supernal exaltation before the magnitude of the mighty buildings; a compelling sorcery was laid upon me by the very lines of their construction, by the harmonies of a solemn architectural music. I forgot my impulse to return to Crater Ridge, and started down the slope toward the city.
>
> Soon the boughs of the purple and yellow forest arched above me like the altitudes of Titan-builded aisles, with leaves that fretted the rich heaven in gorgeous arabesques. Beyond them, ever and anon, I caught glimpses of the piled ramparts of my destination; but looking back in the direction of that other city on the horizon, I found that its fulgurating towers were now lost to view.
>
> I saw, however, that the masses of the great somber cloud were rising steadily on the sky, and once again they flared to a swart, malignant red, as if with some unearthly form of sheet-lightning; and though I could hear nothing with my deadened ears, the ground beneath me trembled with long vibrations as of thunder. There was a queer quality in the vibrations, that seemed to tear my nerves and set my teeth on edge with its throbbing, lancinating discord, painful as broken glass or the torment of a tightened rack.
>
> ...
>
> We had hardly crossed the walls when a weird, flickering glow was cast on the edifices before us by another lightening of the great cloud. The moth-like beings paid no apparent heed, and flew steadily on into the city with their strange faces toward an unseen goal. But, turning my head to peer backward at the storm, I beheld an astounding and appalling spectacle. Beyond the city ramparts, as if wrought by black magic or the toil of genii, another city had reared, and its high towers were moving swiftly forward beneath the rubescent dome of the burning cloud!
>
> A second glance, and I perceived that the towers were identical with those I had beheld afar on the plain. In the interim of my passage through the woods, they had traveled over an expanse of many miles, by means of some unknown motive-power, and had closed in on the City of the Flame. Looking more closely, to determine the manner of their locomotion, I saw that they were not mounted on wheels, but on short, massy legs like jointed columns of metal, that gave them the stride of ungainly colossi. There were six or more of these legs to each tower, and near the tops of the towers were rows of huge eye-like openings, from which issued the bolts of red and violet flame I have mentioned before.
>
> The many-colored forest had been burned away by these flames in a league-wide swath of devastation, even to the walls, and there was nothing but a stretch of black, vaporing desert between the mobile towers and the city. Then, even as I gazed, the long, leaping beams began to assail the craggy ramparts, and the topmost parapets were melting like lava beneath them. It was a scene of utmost terror and grandeur; but, a moment later, it was blotted from my vision by the buildings among which we had now plunged. The great lepidopterous creatures who bore me went on with the speed of eyrie-questing eagles. In the course of that flight, I was hardly capable of conscious thought or volition; I lived only in the breathless and giddy freedom of aerial movement, or dream-like levitation above the labyrinthine maze of stone immensitudes and marvels. I was without actual cognisance of much that I beheld in that stupendous Babel of architectural imageries, and only afterward, in the more tranquil light of recollection, could I give coherent form and meaning to many of my impressions.

Answer (score 2):

There are walking cities in Greg Bear's [*Strength of Stones*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/340815.Strength_of_Stones). I do not remember inter-city wars (hostility, vaguely), nor red lightning, though.

Comment: I haven't read any Bear, so that's not it, I fear.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of John Carter of Mars

http://johncarter.wikia.com/wiki/Zodanga

Comment: That's possible.  I started A Princess of Mars but didn't finish it.

Comment: The city of Zodanga moved in the film, I don't think that was true in the books.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. I recommend a look at our [article](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers. In particular, we encourage participant to include relevant information in their answers and not simply provide a link to that information. Links can expire, and a good answer should be able to survive that.